# How Do I Keep A Random Number From Changing Its Value In The Same Query After Being Generated In Redshift?

Tags: sql, random, amazon-redshift, random-seed

I'm using `random()` in redshift sql query to generate a column, however, when I use this column again in the same query, the values are not the same as the value they were first generated (i.e. every time you use this column again in the same query, sql will generate a new random number), I wonder if I can keep the value of this random number fixed once it is generated? Thanks!

A simple example to explain my issue:

```sql
select random() as a
     , a as b
     , a as c
     , a as d
```

I would expect the `a` in the above query should be the same every time it is used, however if you really run the query above, `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are all different.

Answer (score 2):

use a with block

```
with data
 as (select random() as a
    )
select  a as a
       ,a as b
       ,a as c
       ,a as d
  from data
```

Comment: Thanks George for your answer!

Comment: I don't think Redshift guarantees that such a CTE is evaluated only once.  In fact, the documentation says:  "it **may** be possible to evaluate a WITH subquery once and reuse its results".  That suggests that CTEs are not guaranteed, which is why I specifically did not use a CTE.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do:

```
select . . .
from (select random() as rand) cross join
     . . .
```

The subquery in the `from` clause should be evaluated only once.  It is possible that a CTE would be similar, but I don't know if they are guaranteed to be evaluated only once.

That said, it is possible that this would produce different values on different computation nodes if the optimizer is not set up correctly.

Comment: Thank you Gordon!! So the idea here is to generate it once and use it in other tables.